# how to regex by choose and dynamic params for routing

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, routes

is that possible to create routing `params` regex?

i want to make the dynamic search by rquest.params in but i think it could be dynamic with regex, so i can get that param and then search that key on my database

let say in my field database i have **title, author, subject**
i dont want to create routing request `/:title , /:author, /:subject` for get request, is that possible to create dynamically search on params with regex ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `OR Operator` in mongo like this :

```
$or :[

    {
        title:request.params.title
    },
    {
        author:request.params.author
    },
    {
        subject:request.params.subject
    },

]
```